# Way to access application logs generated by applications deployed in cloudbees app cell

Tags: cloudbees

Wondering is there a way to access the "application logs" being generated by applications deployed in cloudbees app cell setup running tomcat7.

Answer (score 0):

there is a log label on the application manager page (next to configuration,deployments, report..). If you click on it, you should be able to see the logs of your application.

Comment: I have deployed a war file packed with javaagent.jar (under META-INF/extra-files) and the "-javaagent" runtime argument was specified using cloudbees SDK as specified in http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Application+deployment+with+Java+Agent. The javaagent plugged has the behavior to generate it's logs where it exists. Which means, I need to see the logs created in extrafiles/ directory.